# Image error event in Angular is not being called

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

HTML

```
<img
          [src]="url"
          (load)="onImgLoad($event)"
          (error)="onImgError($event)"
          alt=""
        />
```

Typescript

```
onImgLoad(event: any): void {
    console.log('img loaded');
  }

  onImgError(event: any): void {
    console.log('img error');    
  }
```

As the title says my problem is that my error event is just not firing up. When the url is broken and I check console there is a 404 Get error, so this event should fire up if I understand it correctly? Do I have to add some other stuff to the component class for it to work? The load event works correctly.
When I create not existing url I get error in console `GET '*urlHere*' net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` and error event fires up. When url is real I get in console `GET '*urlHere*' 404` and error event is not working.

Comment: Everything checks out. The problem might not be in the code you've shown us but somewhere else. Side note: you can set the type of the `event` parameter to `Event` to be more precise instead of using `any`.

Comment: Can you add to the question the error you seeing in the console?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code. The error event fires ok. make sure you're not refreshing the page so that the error would still be visible.